# Unity-WebGL showing grey window instead of interactive website

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I have a Unity project, where you can navigate around in a 3D space environment. I'm using Unity version 2020.3.4f1 Personal. I went to 'Build settings', chose WebGL, and then clicked 'Build And Run.

The project seems to launch on a Chrome browser in localhost, without any issues:
[image]

However, when I zip the build files & folders (index.html file along with the 'Build' and 'StreamingAssets'), then host as a website, all I get is a grey screen, instead of an interactive website!
[image]

As mentioned the build created is - index.html file, 'Build' folder, and 'StreamingAssets' folder:

[image]

Clearly, there's something wrong with the build as the project seems to run fine directly in localhost.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

### Edit

Looking at the logs in the Chrome browser console (running on localhost), these are the logs:
[image]

For the 404 error, I found some Unity forum thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-builds-only-partially-working.357591/ , where I then thought the solution was to enable Data Caching & Decompression Fallback, and set Compression Format Gzip.

[image]

But this didn't solve the issue, as I still get the 404 in the console log, running on localhost (although as mentioned before, in localhost it runs). Also, when hosting it on a server using Netlify it still shows just a Grey window.

Note: strangely when I refresh the browser running localhost, the 404 disappears, but still the main thing is that when hosted on a remote server (Netlify), I just get a Grey window.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost will be case-insensitive on Windows, while Linux is usually case sensitive on the Host. Check URLs and file names, and try looking at the Web server logs for 404 errors.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by your comment. The project runs fine on localhost. So the issue isn't in running it on localhost. Besides, I don't play around with the code here. I just click the 'Run & Build' option in Unity, and it will build and run the project. As mentioned running the project in Chrome in localhost is fine. When I deploy the build files and folder, exported from Unity, using Netlify to host as a website that's when I get the grey window instead of an interactive site. Netlify built and deployed the website for me and showed no errors. But all I see is a grey window.

Comment: We are not psycic and you don't provide any error analysis. Hint: chrome as a powerful development tool available at a key press: F12. That can show you network 404 errors for example.

Comment: Apologies, I just didn't understand your initial comment as it was a bit vague and didn't mention anything about asking for error logs. I admit I should've checked for error logs, but I'm still quite new to all of this. Anyway, I edited my post now, adding the logs I found in the console. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The 404 is just the favicon, which is optional and not relevant to unity at all. You need to investigate the deprecation warning (1st line) and all those other problems.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever comes across this thread in the future I had the same issues, specifically with Netlify.

I fixed the issue by setting Compression Format to Disabled.